# Where to include a pfx certificate in a http request?

Tags: http-request, certificate

I would like to understand what happens in a request which includes a .pfx certificate to authenticate to client to the server. I know how to implement this in python or use it in postman, but I don't understand what happens in the background. In which part (header, body) of the request is the certificate  included?

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is presented as part of the TLS handshake.

During the handshake, it the server is configured to require a client certificate it will send a CertificateRequest message, the client will then respond with a Certificate message containing your .pfx certificate.

It is not presented as part of the HTTP request

> 1. Client sends ClientHello message proposing SSL options.
> 2. Server responds with ServerHello message selecting the SSL options.
> 3. Server sends Certificate message, which contains the server's certificate.
> 4. Server requests client's certificate in CertificateRequest message, so that the connection can be mutually authenticated.
> 5. Server concludes its part of the negotiation with ServerHelloDone message.
> 6. Client responds with Certificate message, which contains the client's certificate.
> 7. Client sends session key information (encrypted with server's public key) in ClientKeyExchange message.
> 8. Client sends a CertificateVerify message to let the server know it owns the sent certificate.
> 9. Client sends ChangeCipherSpec message to activate the negotiated options for all future messages it will send.
> 10. Client sends Finished message to let the server check the newly activated options.
> 11. Server sends ChangeCipherSpec message to activate the negotiated options for all future messages it will send.
> 12. Server sends Finished message to let the client check the newly activated options.

[Mutual Auth](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326574/An-Introduction-to-Mutual-SSL-Authentication)